# Restore PostgreSQL databes from *.pg_dump file on Windows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pg-restore

I am trying to restore database from *.pg_dump file on windows. I am completely new to PostgreSQL and it could sound easy but I really have a issue with it. I executed this line, but I got no response, no even error, and database is not restored.

```
pg_restore -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d db -F c -b -v -f E:\database.pg_dump
```

Any solution would be great.

Comment: Why did you use "-i" ("a deprecated option that's now ignored") and "-b" (which isn't an option at all)? Start by [carefully reading the syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pgrestore.html).

Comment: If you're using `.bat` (to write restore commands) to restore database then put `pause` in the last line and execute so that you can see what error is coming out

Comment: and also try this restore command `pg_restore -v -d your_database_name "path_to_your_database_backup" 
`